# View history of commands executed using Python in CMD or Powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd

Get-History allows one to view the history of executed commands in Powershell. I am wondering if there is a way for me to execute `dir` with Python using Popen and then use something like Get-History for CMD.exe or Powershell to view the history of that command that Python executed.

Comment: There is no Get-History for cmd.exe. PowerShell cmdlets only work in a PowerShell instance. PowerShell has no idea, what you did using some other executable unless you started it from PowerShell and used redirection (stdout stuff) to send results back to PowerShell. Any command you run from PowerShell is in the PowerShell history. Running external executables from PowerShell is common and well-documented use case. Lots of docs and videos on the topic all over the web adn Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the subprocess from a script, there won't be any history around unless you manually keep track of it in a file somewhere.

If you are calling it from the interactive command line interpreter, it will be stored in the interpreter history, however, it stores each line of code that was interpreted, so you would have to parse the history somehow, targeting only the lines which used popen for instance.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to do see the executed command history unless I stored it in a file?

Comment: Yes. Calling a subprocess is like calling any other function from Python's point of view - the only difference being it hands control to the OS.
With this in mind, it would mean keeping a copy of every line of code you ever executed inside a history file. There are scripts literally thousands of lines long, imagine them constantly executing and filling up some history file. What would be the purpose? The only application would be logging, and that needs to be done by the programmer (granted, there are frameworks for that, but you have to use them on purpose).